# Confused on using SHA256 code from Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, cryptography, sha256

I was looking at Bitcoin Core code to use its SHA256 code but am confused on where I should be looking at.

In bitcoin/src/crypto/sha256.h there is CSHA256

and in bitcoin/src/crypto/sha256.cpp there are namespaces named sha256_sse4, sha256_shani.

And then there is bitcoin/src/hash.h

Explanations and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sha256.h` has the exported (visible from outside) methods and functions. To compute SHA256, you should `#include` that.

- `sha256_sse4.cpp`
- `sha256_sse41.cpp`
- `sha256_avx2.cpp`
- `sha256_shani.cpp`

contain SHA256 transform functions (used in `SHA256.Write`), each specialized for different processors with different instruction sets. Above is the list in order, most of the computers support SSE4, but only a few support SHA-NI instruction set, which is the fastest way a new processor can calculate SHA256.

`sha256.cpp` contains other methods that aren't a bottleneck, functions that check which instruction sets are supported, tests, as well as a pure-C++ transform function for older and non-x86 computers.

`hash.h` favors polymorphism via C++ templates.

Examples:

- [hash `std::vector<something> vch` to `std::vector<something> vchHash`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/78dae8caccd82cfbfd76557f1fb7d7557c7b5edb/src/script/interpreter.cpp#L894)
- [hash `std::vector<something> in`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/de5af41e3567dd9660b3e9734113dccbce394207/src/script/standard.cpp#L28) to [`std::vector<something> WitnessV0ScriptHash`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/de5af41e3567dd9660b3e9734113dccbce394207/src/script/standard.h#L92)
- [hash `uint8_t * nonce.begin()`, `uint8_t *  hash.begin()`, `unsigned char pubkey[]`, `std::vector<unsigned char> vchSig` to `std::vector<unsigned char> entry`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/bccb4d29a8080bf1ecda1fc235415a11d903a680/src/script/sigcache.cpp#L41)
- [hash `op_true` to `witness_program`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/78295e97b8d38ecf6628b5d8ce1efd3900a5c345/src/bench/block_assemble.cpp#L23)